# Passing TreeMap from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-intent, treemap

I've been trying to pass a treemap from one activity to another using intents.

```
public TreeMap<String, ArrayList<SuperMedia>> map = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<SuperMedia>> ();
```

I do it by doing

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.video.tv.MainActivity" );
i.putExtra("map", map);
```

and receive it on the other side by doing

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<SuperMedia>> receivedMap = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<SuperMedia>>) i.getExtras().get("map");
```

Everything works fine. The issue that I'm having is that my SuperMedia class has a field
"ArrayList children", that gets populated on the first activity, but once I pass the TreeMap from one activity to the other the "children" ArrayList shows up empty. I haven't been able to figure out how to solve this issue?

Comment: You put in a TreeMap and pull out a HashMap. Doesn't that throw a ClassCastException?

Comment: and then do map.putAll(receivedMap); No i did not get a ClassCastException